# RAILS: undefined method `budget' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, postman, undefined

I'm new in rails, the thing here is that I'm tryin to create a budget with an specific user ID but when I try to create a budget with postman:

```
{
    "name": "Segundo", "description": "segundo"
}
```

it sends me that message error:

undefined method `budget' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #14):

```
def create
    @budget = current_user.budget.build(budget_params)
    @budget.save 
end
```

**My controller:**

```
class BudgetsController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_id, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def budget_params
    params.require(:budget).permit(:name, :description)
end

def new
    @budget = current_user.budgets.build
    render layout: false
end

def create
    @budget = current_user.budgets.build(budget_params)
    @budget.save 
end

def show
    render json: @budget
end

def edit
    render layout: false
end

def update
    @budget.update(budget_params) 
end

def destroy
    @budget.destroy
end

def find_id
    @budget = Budget.find(params[:id])
end
end
```

**My routes:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :sessions, only: [:create]
  resources :registrations, only: [:create]
  delete :logout, to: "sessions#logout"
  get :logged_in, to: "sessions#logged_in"
  root to: "static#home"
#budgets
resources :budgets

#expenses
resources :expenses, only: [:create, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

#incomes
resources :incomes, only: [:create, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

#investments

resources :investments, only: [:create, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

end
can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Your `current_user` method apparently returns `nil` while your code might expect a `User` object.

Comment: Yeah I think it's because im not using devise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use postman and want to save something in the database that in normal flow only registered users can save, you need to send user session cookies value with your request.
https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/cookies/.
 If you don't send session cookies with your request that means that request is sent by a guest, not logged user. The current_user is nil, so you get undefined method `budget' for nil:NilClass error.

Answer (score 0):

You don't define `current_user` anywhere.  You should probably set a `before_action` where you save the current user, or a base controller your budget controller can inherit from (if you are going to have more controllers that utilize `current_user`).